# Unable to read a database table via parallel JDBC connections: Spark on Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I seek to read and persist into Databricks a 1TB table from a 96-core Amazon RDS Aurora-PostgreSQL DBMS:

```
jdbcHostname = "xxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
jdbcPort = 9999
jdbcDatabase = "123"
username =  "123_usr"
password = "cherrycola"
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase, username, password)
connectionProperties = {
  "user": username,
  "password": password,
  "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"
}
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table="every_housecat", column="autoincrementing_indexed_housecat_id", lowerBound=12, upperBound=2760259875, numPartitions=96-4, properties=connectionProperties)
```

The above commands all work (although I don't know why the final command takes 10 minutes rather than 1) being fairly instantaneous and not transferring data; or 2) performing the entire read of the table (basically, I don't get what it's doing)).

Then, I execute:

```
out = df.write.saveAsTable('every_housecat')
```

After 55 minutes, this above command fails with:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3565195489540506> in <module>
----> 1 out = df.write.saveAsTable('every_housecat')
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in saveAsTable(self, name, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    866         if format is not None:
    867             self.format(format)
--> 868 self._jwrite.saveAsTable(name)
    869 
    870     @since(1.4)
/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1304         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 
   1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    125     def deco(*a, **kw):
```

When I inspect the cluster logs I see "Executor heartbeat timed out after […]".

From the PostgreSQL side, I can confirm that during those 55 minutes all 92 cores are in-use near 100% and heavy client-writes are performed, and that there is no locking which blocks said reads.

I am brand new to Spark and Databricks and do not really know what I am doing. It is entirely possible that my essential strategy is poor—bear that in mind! Once again, I am merely trying by hook or by crook to import this table into Databricks, persist it, and then naturally to perform transformations and analysis.

I've been banging my head for a while, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

*(cross-posted at https://forums.databricks.com/questions/45980/unable-to-read-a-database-table-into-via-parallel.html)*

Comment: Hey, I'm still seeking insight, if anyone has hypotheses…

Comment: Hi, found any solution to this? I am facing similar issues.

Comment: @thijsvdp No, not really. My untested hypothesis is that I could actually only perform one table scan at a time with my source RDBMS, and thus attempting parallel scans (even with a partitioning scheme based on an indexed column) set off a clusterfuck.

In my particular case, because I am using Amazon RDS Aurora-PostgreSQL DBMS, I was able to use RDS' UI to create a Parquet dump to S3 (~12 hours). Hope this helps.

Comment: I already solved my issue luckily, and now I read your question again, it was definitely a different problem. What are you trying to do with `df.write.saveAsTable`? I never used this command, but according to the documentation it is saving your results into a Hive table. It also says that you need additional dependencies on all your nodes for this. Is this what you want or do you want to write back to the db you read from?